# parameters passing in testNG.xml

Tags: testng

I have written this code for Login into Yahoo:
public class ParametersTestClass {

```
WebDriver driver;

@Test
@Parameters({"url","emailId"})
    public void YohaooLoginTest(String url,String emailId)
{
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\Ankita Jaiswal\\Downloads\\SETUPS\\chromedriver.exe");
    driver=new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get(url);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='uh-signin']")).click();  //why it was not working?

    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='login-username']")).sendKeys(emailId);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='login-signin']")).click();

}
}
```

and passed the value of the parameter of url and emailID in testNG.xml but on execution, it is not clicking on Sign in button.

On commenting Sign in button, it is working correctly.
Can anybody please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try to click it using Action class or JavaScriptExecutor,

```
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
builder.moveToElement("Target Webelement").click().perform();
```

OR

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;  
js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();","Target Webelement");
```